# Troubleshooting a Magento / Solr connectivity issue

Tags: solr

Working with Magento EE 1.14.2.4 running on CentOS LAMP stack. Attempting to utilize Solr Search.

I'm creating a staging site. The codebase and server configuration are essentially mirrors of production. Everything seems configured correctly but when I attempt to run ***Test Connection*** of Solr from System > Config > Catalog > Catalog > Catalog Search I get "**Connection failed! Test again?**".

I know I'm running Solr, I'm starting it up with this command which is taken from the Magento 1.x / Solr doc:

java -jar /root/solr/apache-solr-3.6.2/example/start.jar

Dev Document: http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/m1x/other/ht_magento-solr.html

To rule out any firewalls or security rules, I monitored incoming traffic to Solr's default port (i.e. 8983):

```
tcpdump -i eth0 port 8983
```

Ran the test from Magento's admin, no incoming traffic/packets.

I then ran the following command to ensure the port was open and receiving:

```
wget mysstagingsite.com:8983
```

404, but at least a server response and a visible request in my tcpdump.

Also to be clear: My codebase, database and Solr instance are all hosted on a single environment, so the request Solr would be making would be to 127.0.0.1:8983, so I tested this command as well:

```
wget 127.0.0.1:8983
```

Same result, packets and request visible.

For whatever reason, the Solr connectivity test in the admin isn't actually requesting anything - it seems. So what could be wrong? Solr was part of Magento EE, all I did was install according to the dev docs provided by Magento and it worked on my production site. How do I proceed with debugging as there isn't necessarily a Magento extension to reinstall?